# How can I update an array field with a batch write operation in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to update an array of maps in my document while creating a new document in a sub-collection but couldn't make it work:

```
export const addTask = async (data, caseId) => {
  let batch = await db.batch();

  const caseRef = db.collection("cases").doc(caseId);
  const taskRef = caseRef.collection("tasks").doc();

  try {
    await batch.set(taskRef, data);
    await batch.set(caseRef, {
      tasks: db.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data),
    }, {merge:true});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return batch.commit();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the issues:

- use batch.update on the second batch call if the array field already exists on the parent doc and just needs to be updated.
- FieldValue.arrayUnion isn't a method on the client instance of firestore. Use *firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion* from the global firebase namespace to update the array. Check the guide on [updating arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)
- `{merge:true}` is not required as arrayUnion will add data to the existing set unless it already exists.

```js
    export const addTask = async (data, caseId) => {

      let batch = await db.batch();

      const caseRef = db.collection("cases").doc(caseId);
      const taskRef = caseRef.collection("tasks").doc();

      try {
        await batch.set(taskRef, data);
        await batch.update(caseRef, {
          tasks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data),
        });
       }catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
       }
 
      return batch.commit();
     }
```